# I am trying to create a basic damage calculator in C#, but something is not working properly

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a very basic damage calculator but for some reason when I run the program and set the values it comes out as 0. Here is my code:

In AbilityDamage.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1.Files
{
    class AbilityDamage
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter ability name:");
            string abilityName = Console.ReadLine();

            Ability RocketGrab = new Ability();
            Ability MegaInfernoBomb = new Ability();
            Ability Cataclysm = new Ability();
            Ability MysticShot = new Ability();
            Ability SuperMegaDeathRocket = new Ability();
            Ability Hemoplague = new Ability();
            Ability SprayAndPray = new Ability();
            Ability BusterShot = new Ability();
            Ability AssaultAndBattery = new Ability();
            Ability ExplosiveCask = new Ability();
            Ability PiercingArrow = new Ability();
            Ability Sear = new Ability();

            if (abilityName == "Rocket Grab")
            {
                RocketGrab.AbilityDamageCalculator();
            }
            else if (abilityName == "Mega Inferno Bomb")
            {
                MegaInfernoBomb.AbilityDamageCalculator();
            }
            else if (abilityName == "Cataclysm")
            {
                Cataclysm.AbilityDamageCalculator();
            }
            else if (abilityName == "Mystic Shot")
            {
                MysticShot.AbilityDamageCalculator();
            }
            else if (abilityName == "Super Mega Death Rocket")
            {
                SuperMegaDeathRocket.AbilityDamageCalculator();
            }
            else if (abilityName == "Hemoplague")
            {
                Hemoplague.AbilityDamageCalculator();
            }
            else if (abilityName == "Spray and Pray")
            {
                SprayAndPray.AbilityDamageCalculator();
            }
            else if (abilityName == "Buster Shot")
            {
                BusterShot.AbilityDamageCalculator();
            }
            else if (abilityName == "Assault and Battery")
            {
                AssaultAndBattery.AbilityDamageCalculator();
            }
            else if (abilityName == "Explosive Cask")
            {
                ExplosiveCask.AbilityDamageCalculator();
            }
            else if (abilityName == "Piercing Arrow")
            {
                PiercingArrow.AbilityDamageCalculator();
            }
            else if (abilityName == "Sear")
            {
                Sear.AbilityDamageCalculator();
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Ability not recognized.");
            }

            RocketGrab.name = "Rocket Grab";
            RocketGrab.baseDamage = 80;
            RocketGrab.apRatio = 1;
            MegaInfernoBomb.name = "Mega Inferno Bomb";
            MegaInfernoBomb.baseDamage = 250;
            MegaInfernoBomb.apRatio = 0.9;
            Cataclysm.name = "Cataclysm";
            Cataclysm.baseDamage = 200;
            Cataclysm.adRatio = 1.5;
            MysticShot.name = "Mystic Shot";
            MysticShot.baseDamage = 35;
            MysticShot.adRatio = 1;
            MysticShot.apRatio = 0.2;
            SuperMegaDeathRocket.name = "Super Mega Death Rocket";
            SuperMegaDeathRocket.baseDamage = 125;
            SuperMegaDeathRocket.adRatio = 0.5;
            Hemoplague.name = "Hemoplague";
            Hemoplague.baseDamage = 150;
            Hemoplague.apRatio = 0.7;
            SprayAndPray.name = "Spray and Pray";
            SprayAndPray.baseDamage = 20;
            BusterShot.name = "Buster Shot";
            BusterShot.baseDamage = 300;
            BusterShot.apRatio = 1.5;
            AssaultAndBattery.name = "Assault and Battery";
            AssaultAndBattery.baseDamage = 200;
            AssaultAndBattery.adRatio = 1.4;
            ExplosiveCask.name = "Explosive Cask";
            ExplosiveCask.baseDamage = 200;
            ExplosiveCask.apRatio = 1;
            PiercingArrow.name = "Piercing Arrow";
            PiercingArrow.baseDamage = 10;
            PiercingArrow.adRatio = 1;
            Sear.name = "Sear";
            Sear.baseDamage = 80;
            Sear.apRatio = 0.65;
        }
    }
}
```

And in CalculateDamage.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1.Files
{
    class Ability
    {
        public double baseDamage;
        public double apRatio;
        public double adRatio;
        public string name;

        public void AbilityDamageCalculator()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter your ap value:");
            double ap = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Enter your ad value:");
            double ad = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            double bonusDamage = apRatio * ap + adRatio * ad;
            double totalDamage = baseDamage + bonusDamage;
            Console.WriteLine(name + "deals " + totalDamage + " damage at level 1.");
        }
    }
}
```

Any help with this problem will be much appreciated!

Comment: Run it line-by-line in the debugger.

Comment: Check out https://compilify.net put your example on there to allow people to play around with it and see what's not working

Comment: Take a look at an abstract factory pattern to greatly improve readability.  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/328373/Understanding-and-Implementing-Abstract-Factory-Pa  or at least add some basic OO with an `Ability` interface.

Answer (score 4):

All your values are set in the main method.

When you have a rocket grab it will perform

```
RocketGrab.AbilityDamageCalculator();
```

but inside this method there are no values. Both of these will be 0 and thus return 0 when multiplied.

```
public double apRatio;
public double adRatio;
```

You have to create an appropriate object and set the values of the ratios if you want to make it work. Better would be to rethink your concept and start creating subclasses that have these values hardcoded inside them (or think of a datasource like a database).

The moment you actually set the basevalues and other values for an ability, you're already done with the calculating.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're not initializing the values for your abilities until after you've asked the user for input and performed the calculations.

Answer (score 2):

```
  public double baseDamage;
  public double apRatio;
  public double adRatio;
  public string name;
```

You never set values for this variables. Therefore

```
  double bonusDamage = apRatio * ap + adRatio * ad;
  double totalDamage = baseDamage + bonusDamage;
```

equals

```
 double bonusDamage = 0 * ap +0* ad;
 double totalDamage = 0 + bonusDamage;
```

which would be 0.